# How can I protect an AWS API Gateway endpoint that will be called by a Java application?

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Here is what I've got:

- A Java application that lives outside of AWS.
- An AWS API Gateway endpoint that triggers a Node.js Lambda function.

Here is my question:

How can I protect the endpoint so that only my Java application can be authorized to call the AWS API Gateway endpoint?

Comment: Whitelist the IP address of the server running the external Java application, [see here](https://lobster1234.github.io/2018/04/14/amazon-api-gateway-ip-whitelisting/).

Comment: I would use IAM Roles - take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-roles.html

Answer (score 2):

You can protect your API from unauthorized access by **Turning on the API authentication** in your API Gateway & **Granting the user access** for your API to you IAM users.

[AWS API GATEWAY RESOURCE EXPLAINING THE SAME](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/control-access-to-your-apis-using-amazon-api-gateway-resource-policies/)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to protect the API from unauthorized access, e.g. AWS Cognito, IAM roles, custom authorizers, resource policies. But they may appear an overkill for a simple use case (when just one application is authorized to access).

Consider [API Keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html) granting access to your API endpoint - a simple way to control access to your API. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-setup-api-key-with-console.html) is how to set it up.